# I wanted to know what can I use to place objects anywhere in a website, like positioning a table in any part of the website? Thank you

Tags: position

I'm new to HTML and I would like to know how to place any object in any part of the website, for example, a table between the center and the left side. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is about the structure of your website and webpage. Once you have the structure with all the elements written in HTML, you can customise their display and position through CSS (it's another language). Check this page to get a first understanding of how it looks like https://www.w3schools.com/css/.